# What is difference between autoReconnect & autoReconnectForPools in MySql connector/J?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

In the configuration reference for MySql's [connector J driver](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), a caveat emptor is issued on the use of the **autoReconnect** property. I followed the instructions and increased my server's *wait_timeout*. Since I am using DBCP (I am considering moving to c3po after reading several posts on Stackoverflow shooting down DBCP ), is it ok to use the **autoReconnectForPools** property ? What does it actually do when enabled under DBCP or any connection pool for that matter ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

autoReconnect will throw an SQLException to the client, but will try to re-establish the connection.

autoReconnectForPools will try to ping the server before each SQL execution.

I had a lot of issues with dbcp in the past, especially disconnections. Most were solved by moving to [c3p0](http://c3p0.sourceforge.net/). Notice that the mysql driver has connection tester for c3p0 (com.mysql.jdbc.integration.c3p0.MysqlConnectionTester).

Also, you may want to check this out: [Connection pooling options with JDBC: DBCP vs C3P0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0)

Comment: Generally, more modern pools such as HikariCP or Tomcat DBCP will use the ``Connection.isValid()`` method.  There is also a *special* query that only MySQL recognizes, "/* ping \*/" (must be *exactly* that), which will cause MySQL to use a lightweight *ping* to the server.  I believe the ``isValid()`` implementation should still be more efficient, as the "/* ping \*/" query must still be processed by the parser.

Answer (score 9):

MySQL's `autoReconnect` feature is deprecated, as it has many issues (ref: official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)).

`autoReconnectForPools` has little to do with `autoReconnect`, it has more to do with `autoCommit` and `reconnectAtTxEnd` - when all 3 are `true`, it will ping the server at the end of each transaction and automatically reconnect if needed.

DBCP's connection validation is imperfect - even when `testOnBorrow` is set, it sometimes returns broken connections from the pool (not to mention testing a connection before every borrow is horribly inefficient).

According to [this article](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Bad-Behavior:-Handling-Database-Down), HikariCP seems to be a better pool implementation, as it is able to use JDBC4 `isValid()` API which is much faster than running a test query, and is specially designed to never return broken connections to the client application.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're using DBCP properly?

According to the [short configuration notes](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html), it's supposed to handle timeouts pretty well thanks to the default value of `testOnBorrow=true` (tests the connection before used, and if it fails it is dropped from the pool and we try to get a new one instead).

*The only thing you need to do* is to make sure you configure the `validationQuery` property to a non-null String, e.g. "SELECT 0" for MySQL database ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases) is a post about different validationQuery values per DB used).