# DBCP - validationQuery for different Databases

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I use DBCP pool and I want use *testOnBorrow* and *testOnReturn* to test if connection is still valid.
Unfortunately I have to set property validationQuery to make it work.

Question: **What value should be in validationQuery?**

I know, that: validationQuery must be an SQL SELECT statement, that returns at least one row.

Problem is that we use various databases (DB2, Oracle, hsqldb).

Comment: Does using validationQuery not degrade the performance? This query runs for every connection the application gets right?

Comment: @yaswanth It's usually only run once at startup I would imagine, unless you have some special circumstance

Answer (score 229, accepted):

There is not only one validationQuery for all databases. On each database you have to use different validationQuery.

After few hours of googling and testing I have collected this table:

Database      validationQuery   notes

- **hsqldb** - `select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS`
- **Oracle** - `select 1 from dual`
- **DB2** - `select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1`
- **mysql** - `/* ping */ select 1`
- **microsoft SQL Server** - `select 1` (tested on SQL-Server 9.0, 10.5 [2008])
- **postgresql** - `select 1`
- **ingres** - `select 1`
- **derby** - `values 1`
- **H2** - `select 1`
- **Firebird** - `select 1 from rdb$database`
- **MariaDb** - `select 1`
- **Informix** - `select 1 from systables`
- **Hive** - `select 1`
- **Impala** - `select 1`

I wrote about it on my blog - [validation query for various databases](http://vondrnotes.blogspot.com/2012/05/validationquery-for-different-databases.html).

In advance there is an example of class, which return validationQuery according to JDBC driver.

Or does anybody have better solution?

Comment: select 1 is also valid on postgresql

Comment: `select 1` also works for Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64), Feb 20 2014 20:04:26, Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: `select 1` for Hive and Impala

Answer (score 15):

For MySQL with the Connector/J driver, there's a lightweight validation query that just sends a ping to the server and returns a dummy result set.
The validation query can be (or should start with) exactly the following string:

```
/* ping */
```

For more infor refer to the [Validating Connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html) in the MySQL driver manual

Answer (score 4):

For Informix, The validation query is,
select 1 from systables

Comment: Thanks - I have just added it to list

Answer (score 1):

For MairaDB validation query is  "select 1" .

Comment: Thanks - I have just added it to list