# attempt to reconnect jdbc pool datasource after database restarts

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource, jdbc-pool

I have a web-app with a Java back-end that uses [Tomcat jdbc-pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html) for database connections. This works fine.

However I am trying to foolproof it before exporting it to other locations, and recently a scenario occurred where someone restarted the SQL Server database service but did not restart the Tomcat service. This caused a SQLException: `java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error` until I restarted Tomcat, forcing the jdbc-pool datasource to reconnect.

I looked for some kind of a configuration in the Tomcat jdbc-pool docs to tell the datasource to attempt to reconnect but I couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know if there is some kind of configuration for this or should I check this condition before each request?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is your problem but on http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency it says you can use `testOnBorrow` with a `validationQuery`.

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            ...
            testOnBorrow="true"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            />
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the validation query overhead, and found another method in that same link using `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"` and `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="5000"` and `minIdle="0"` that seems to handle the problem, thanks.

Comment: @Geronimo: well I upvoted your comment yesterday but today I realized that using `minIdle="0"` may actually be worse: it's actually closing the connection after 5s of inactivity, whether it's fine or not. So I'm not sure what's worse: executing `SELECT 1` before each query or having to reconnect every 5s of inactivity...

Comment: the `testOnBorrow="true"` will auto start a new connection if found the old connection is closed?

Comment: That original link is gone, but it was recorded by the wayback machine:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180521112213/http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency

Answer (score 1):

While checking for the same issue I came across this post which has the auto connect configurations for all app servers.

Below are the configuration which I used for auto connect in tomcat for reference.

```
    <Resource auth="Container"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
initialSize="5"
maxActive="120"
maxIdle="5"
maxWait="5000"
name="jdbc/oracle/myds"
password="secret"
poolPreparedStatements="true"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@DBHOSTNAME:1521/ServiceName"
username="testuser"
validationQuery="select 1 from tab"
testOnBorrow="true"/>
```

Complete auto connect configurations for all app servers can be found here in [Datasource autoreconnect in Java Application Servers](http://www.techpaste.com/2016/04/jndi-autoreconnect-java-application-servers/).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to Natan Cox's answer

Reference - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        ...
        testOnBorrow="true"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        />
```

As against Geronimo, I would still like to use validationQuery

**Database validationQuery notes**

**hsqldb** - `select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS`

**Oracle** - `select 1 from dual`

**DB2** - `select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1`

**mysql** - `select 1`

**microsoft SQL Server** - `select 1`

**postgresql** - `select 1`

**ingres** - `select 1`

**derby** - `values 1`

**H2** - `select 1`

**Firebird** - `select 1 from rdb$database`

Reference - [DBCP - validationQuery for different Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases)

Comment: the testOnBorrow="true" will auto start a new connection if found the old connection is closed?