# Spring Boot - Tomcat jdbc connection pool does not recover after database server is restarted

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, tomcat-jdbc

I have a Spring Boot (1.5.17) web application with Tomcat JDBC connection pool (8.5.34) configured as follows:

```
primary.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true 
primary.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
primary.datasource.validationInterval=35000
primary.datasource.initial-size=10
primary.datasource.max-active=50
primary.datasource.max-idle=20
primary.datasource.min-idle=10
```

Now if I restart the database server (SQL Server) I get the `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed` exception and the connection pool does not recover.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [attempt to reconnect jdbc pool datasource after database restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301707/attempt-to-reconnect-jdbc-pool-datasource-after-database-restarts)

Comment: Nope. I already checked that question and answer. I checked other similar questions but no solution has helped me yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error. I made a mistake while writing the configuration key `primary.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow`. It should be `primary.datasource.testOnBorrow`. And now it is working fine. The connection pool recovers almost immediately after database server restarts.

Here is my final configuration for anyone if they are having similar problems.

```
primary.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
primary.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
primary.datasource.validationInterval=55000
primary.datasource.initial-size=5
primary.datasource.min-idle=5
primary.datasource.max-idle=10
primary.datasource.max-active=20
primary.datasource.removeAbandoned=true
```