# Check if connection of database is live in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In mysql before critical database operations i am checking if connection to database is live running a simple query mostly

```
 select now()
```

Can there be a suitable alternative in hibernate not selecting from any tables but selecting anything generic like current time in earlier case to check if connection to database is live.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally done not at Hibernate but at connection pool configuration level.

E.g. c3p0 has `idle_test_period`, `preferredTestQuery` and `testConnectionOnCheckout`; dbcp has [`validationQuery`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) and so on.

As for SQL, I don't believe something generic exists. But there's a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases) for this purpose already.