# Not able to send jdbc request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle for JDBC request in JMeter.

Configuration details:

[image]

Suggest if any changes required to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your add [Oracle JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter afterwars.
2. I am not sure that copying and pasting [tnsnames.ora](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm) into the JDBC URL is supported, as far as I'm aware you need to set `oracle.net.tns_admin` [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) and use TNS entry in the JDBC URL like `jdbc:oracle:thin:@your_entry_name_here`
3. I also believe you should change your "Validation query" to `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`

More information:

- [DBCP - validationQuery for different Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases)
- [Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm)
- [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)

Comment: I made the changes as per your suggetion, still could not able to resolve the issue. see the logs and Response data for SQL select

2017/07/18 08:17:28 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement: Could not return Connection java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for oracle.tcdms.db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@do2701.oracle.uprr.com:1521:do2701

Response Data : 

No suitable driver found for oracle.tcdms.db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@do2701.oracle.uprr.com:1521:do2701

Comment: Can you elaborate the solution and let me know if you want more details