# Jmeter throws Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory for DB2

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

Jmeter Version 3.2

I have copied jar files db2jcc.jar, db2jcc4.jar and db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar to the lib directory.

When i executed the jdbc request getting the below error.Not sure what else I am missing.

Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=END-OF-STATEMENT;Select 1;, DRIVER=3.58.82).

See the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to incorrect `Validation Query`, default `Select 1` won't fit for DB2, change it to one of the following:

- `select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1`

Alternatives are:

- `values 1`
- `values current date`
- or any other query which doesn't take long to execute and guaranteed to work

References:

- [DBCP - validationQuery for different Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases)
- [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)