# how to turn bash command into docker(-compose) healthcheck

Tags: bash, oracle, docker, docker-compose, health-monitoring

I'm using [sath89/oracle-12c](https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/oracle-12c/) for automated tests against a oracle db.
This works fine, the only problem is that this container takes several minutes to start (~10-15 depending on the hardware).
I tried to come up with a healthcheck for this container.

I managed to come up with

```
status=`su oracle -c "echo -e \"SELECT ACCOUNT_STATUS FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME = 'ANONYMOUS' AND ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'EXPIRED';\" | /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/xe/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba | grep ACCOUNT_STATUS"`; if [ "$status" == "ACCOUNT_STATUS" ]; then true; else false; fi
```

which returns 0 when the `ANONYMOUS` account is unlocked, which is the last step in the `entrypoint` script of the image: [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/MaksymBilenko/docker-oracle-12c/blob/master/entrypoint.sh#L85).
I tested this using `docker exec -it <containername> bash`.

I am now stuck with converting this horribly long line into a healthcheck command for docker (docker-compose):

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    image: sath89/oracle-12c:r1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "<command goes here>"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
```

Any help is appreciated - if you can improve the command itself I'm happy to here.
I am aware of "select 1 from dual" as a validation query for Oracle ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases)), but this reports an operational DB after ~8 minutes but it resets connections a little bit later.
I don't want to modify the container itself - if there's an update I just want to be able to pull it from the hub.

Comment: Why don't you put the command into a bash script and add it to the image? Comming to your question, according to the [docu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck), the command is executed via `exec`, thus you have to invoke `bash` and give it your script: `test: ["CMD", "bash", "-c", "<horrible long script>"]`.

Comment: I just realized you could also let `docker-compose` do the job of invoking the shell, though it uses `/bin/sh`: `test: ["CMD-SHELL", "<horrible long script>"]`

Comment: @fzgregor thanks for the hint to "CMD-SHELL" again. I stumbled across it myself but somehow ignored it. I have given it another try and it looks promising, will post an answer if it actually works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so after quite some time I've come up with an solution for my problem. I could simplify the "" a bit:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  db:
    image: sath89/oracle-12c:r1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "if [ \"`echo \\\"SELECT ACCOUNT_STATUS FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME = 'ANONYMOUS' AND ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'EXPIRED';\\\"|/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/xe/bin/sqlplus -S sys/oracle as sysdba|grep ACCOUNT_STATUS`\" = \"ACCOUNT_STATUS\" ];then true;else false;fi"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 3s
      # start_period: 900s
      retries: 30
```

Right now "docker-compose" does not support the start_period option so the numbers of retries (and the interval) have to be quite high so the container isn't reported as "unhealthy".
The [Pull Request](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/475) has already been merged so hopefully it will be in the next release.