# Getting Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure) in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to connect jmeter with the database and getting this exception after 20 seconds.

Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with JMeter, the error you're getting indicates that the [JDBC Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) cannot communicate with the database server.

Checklist:

1. Make sure that the database server is up and running and listening on an external [network interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface) (sometimes by default the database is bond to the localhost)
2. Make sure that the port is open in your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))
3. Cross-check the JDBC driver version as in case of mismatch the communication may fail
4. Double check the [validation query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases), there are some presets for different database types in the [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

   [image]
5. Look for suspicious entries in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it's possible to [increase the JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for JDBC test elements by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc" level="debug" />
   ```