# Problem in Oracle JDBC Connection Configuration/JDBC Request - JMETER

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jmeter

I'm a problem in JDBC Connection Configuration. When i execute my test (only JDBC Request - insert), doesn't appear any results in report (View Results Tree):

*"Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:JDTST'"*

The connection is Oracle. See below the configuration:

**database URL**: jdbc:oracle://${myURL}

**JDBC driver Class**: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

**Username**: ${user}

**Password**: ${password}

Print below:
[image]

lister.ora file:
[image]

My login in Oracle DB:

[image]

Could someone help me?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think your URL is correct, it should be something like:

   ```
   jdbc:oracle:thin:@your-oracle-hostname-or-ip-address:your-oracle-port:your-oracle-SID
   ```
2. Correct JDBC Driver fully qualified name is `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`
3. The "Validation query" should be `select 1 from dual`
4. You will need to download [Oracle JDBC Driver](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

More information:

- [OracleDriver Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)
- [DBCP - validationQuery for different Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10684260/2897748)
- [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)

Comment: Dmitri T,

- My URL:  jdbc:oracle:thin:@${JDTST}
- JDBC Driver: I tried with oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver and oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
- I changed "Validation query" to select 1 from dual.

Error again.. =/
See below:

:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL ' jdbc:oracle:thin:@JDTST'

Comment: DmitriT, 
I added a print of the listener.ora file in description.

How would I get his URL?

Comment: I added other print in description, about my login in Oracle DB!

Comment: ??? =/ !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [JDBC Developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-77AF8002-36FB-41C5-8381-6A53B0C443AE) on how the JDBC connection URL is formed.
The easiest way is to use the below URL. You can use [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/main/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) for checking the connection.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:db_user/db_password@localhost:5221:orcl
```

Comment: Nirmala, I added the URL but to no avail... =/

Comment: I added other print in description, about my login in Oracle DB!

Comment: ??? =/ !!!!!!!!!

Comment: Can you check tnsnames.ora on the database side and verify if the connection works through sqlplus?

Answer (score 1):

Database SID is no longer supported; please use a service name as in Nirmala's response.

Comment: But it doesn't work...
I tried:
jdbc:oracle:thin:CAMILA_JDCCS2019/keyUser@localhost:5221:orcl

Comment: The error below:
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Erro de ES: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)