# Jmeter error org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection.isValid(I)Z

Tags: postgresql, jmeter

I am geting the following error when i run a test scenario...I am using

> postgresql-42.4.1 jar ,

java.lang.AbstractMethodError:    org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection.isValid(I)Z    at
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:590)
~[commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]    at
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:334)
~[commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]    at
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:653)
~[commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]    at
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:109)
~[commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]    at
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:649)
~[commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]    at
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:531)
~[commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]    at
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)
~[commons-dbcp2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]    at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement$DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:362)
~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.5]    at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:199)
~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.5]    at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:80)
~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.5]    at
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)
~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]    at
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)
~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]    at
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)
~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]    at
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]    at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

[image]

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: why i get this error?? i cant fix it is my problem ,i cant run queries. . everythink is correct but ...

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Simply dumping a stacktrace does not enable others to reproduce the problem to provide help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SELECT 1` as the validation query:

[image]

More information:

- [DBCP - validationQuery for different Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases)
- [How to use Different JDBC Drivers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732729-How-to-use-Different-JDBC-Drivers)

Comment: Validation Query was the problem.... i worked... Thank you alot!