# JMeter MSSQL connection issue

Tags: sql, jmeter

So I am using the following

```
Jmeter 5.5
Java 17.0.2
mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre18.jar
```

The jar has been installed to the JMeter/lib folder

In the JMeter JDBC Connection Configuration

```
Database URL is like this: jdbc:sqlserver://xx-xxxxxxxx;DatabaseName=xxxxxx
JDBC driver class is: com.mircrosoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
Username and password are valid
```

When I run the test all I get is this:

Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mircrosoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'

The SQL Server is version 15.0.4223

Any ideas please

Comment: Are you trying to use a library for Java 18 in a Java 17 jvm? That won't load...

Comment: Either upgrade to java 18 (I would NOT do this) or downgrade the JDBC driver to java 17 (most likely a solution).

Comment: Good point, so now I have placed mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre17.jar in the lib folder and removed the other jar. After restarting JMeter and trying again I still get the same error

Comment: Did you copy the JDBC driver into `<JMETER_HOME>/lib`? That should be enough. Now, I see a misspelling in the driver name, right there in the error message. `mircrosoft` --> `microsoft` maybe?

Comment: Thanks, it was the spelling, oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, the [driver class name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver16#make-a-simple-connection-to-a-database) should be:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

and the [Validation Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases) should be `select 1`

More information: [How to use Different JDBC Drivers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732729-How-to-use-Different-JDBC-Drivers)