# Resource leak warning in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, resource-leak

In `Eclipse` I received a warning `Resource leak: 'ps' is not closed at this location` that I don't understand.

In my `Java` code I declare the **"ps"** as a Prepared Statement and I use (and close) it many times. Then I've the following sequence:

```
try {
    if(condition) {
        ps = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE 1 ...");
    } else {
        ps = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE 2 ...");
    }
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // exception handling
} finally {
    if (null != ps) 
        try { 
            ps.close(); 
        } catch (SQLException e) { 
            // exception handling
        };
}
```

The "Resource leak"-Warning comes on the "Update"-Statement in the else section.
If I set `ps = null` before I start the try block, there is no warning.

If the second UPDATE-Statement is commented out, no warning will be shown.

Is that an understanding or a java / eclipse problem?

Comment: My guess is that Eclipse is detecting that you're using the prepared statement object previously and due to potential for the SQLException may not close it properly. If you do `ps = null;` in the finally block it'll probably be fixed and this would be a more rational place to clean it up.

Answer (score 11):

If you have this warning you are using Java 7. In this case you should not close the resource that implements `AutoClosable` yourself. You should initialize those resources in special initialization section of `try` statementcommented:

```
// decide which update statement you need:
// (your if should be here)
String update = ....;
try (
     ps = c.prepareStatement(update);
) {
   // use prepared statement here.
} catch (SQLException) {
   // log your exception
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
// no finally block is needed. The resource will be closed automatically.
```

I indeed do not know why presence of `if/else` statement causes the warning to appear or disappear. But java 7 recommends the way to work with auto closable resources that I described above, so try this.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out. Since I'm not yet ready to fully commit to Java 7 I've just told Eclipse to set resource leaks to ignore.  Probably dangerous, but will work for now.

Answer (score 3):

I think, it's a problem with the checker that your are using.

Break your code into `initialization` and `use` blocks.  Also, throw exception out of the initialization block ( or do an early return ).  This way there is no need to check for null when you release the resource after `use` block

```
// initialization
// Note that ps is declared final.
// I think it will help to silence your checker
final PreparedStatement ps;

try {
    if( bedingungen ... ) {
        ps = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE 1 ...");
    } else {
        ps = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE 2 ...");
    }
} 
catch (SQLException e) {
    log.error("Problem creating prepared statement, e );
    throw e;
}

// use
try {
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    log.error("Problem decrementing palets on " + srcElement.getName() + 
        ": " +    e.getMessage());
}
finally {
    try {
        ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.warn("Error closing PreparedStatement: " + e.getMessage());
    };
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Change the variable name from c to mC. I think it's a weird glitch while using c as a variable name. Thanks Charlie