# Resource Leak: 'ps' may not be closed at this location

Tags: java, jdbc

Take a look at this simple database query method that is giving me the warning `Resource Leak: 'ps' may not be closed at this location` in the return line..

```
public Bancos getDefault() {
    Debug.out("");

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Bancos banco = null;

    try {

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_BANCOS + " " +
                       "WHERE " + FIELD_KEY + " = ?;";

        ps = connector.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, new ParametrosManager().getParametros().getCodigoBanco());

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            banco = new Bancos(
                    rs.getString(FIELD_KEY),
                    rs.getDate(FIELD_DATAREGISTO),
                    rs.getString(FIELD_ABREVIATURA),
        }

        rs.close();
        ps.close();

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(ps != null) 
                ps.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return banco;
}
```

I wonder why **eclipse** gives me this warning since I'm even closing `ps` on a `finally` block. Would this be just a false positive warning?

I use Java 7.

**SOLUTION:**

It seems to be a problem with Java 7, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863156/1959761) from the duplicate question.

So, the fixed code:

```
public Bancos getDefault() {
    Debug.out("");

    Bancos banco = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_BANCOS + " " +
                   "WHERE " + FIELD_KEY + " = ?;";

    try( PreparedStatement ps = connector.prepareStatement(query); ) {
        ps.setString(1, new ParametrosManager().getParametros().getCodigoBanco());

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            banco = new Bancos(
                    rs.getString(FIELD_KEY),
                    rs.getDate(FIELD_DATAREGISTO),
                    rs.getString(FIELD_ABREVIATURA),
        }

        rs.close();

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

    return banco;
}
```

My thanks to [Luiggi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza) for pointing me to the answer.

Comment: what Eclipse version do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption that this warning is a false positive is correct.

Testing your code in Eclipse 4.5 I don't receive any warning. Seems that static analysis in the Eclipse Java compiler improved in the meantime.