# Multiple annotations found at this line: Resource leak: 'resultSet' is not closed at this location

Tags: java, jsp

I closed result set but its till showing warning "Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Resource leak: 'resultSet' is not closed at this 
     location
    - Resource leak: 'resultSet' is not closed at this 
     location"

```
<% 
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sm_db", "root", "root");

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;
        DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet resultSet;
        resultSet = metadata.getTables(null, null, "SmartMiner", null);
        while(resultSet.next())
                {
                //table exists
                try{
                resultSet=statement.executeQuery("SELECT*FROM SmartMiner") ;    
                }finally{
                    resultSet.close();
                }

    %>

    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table BORDER="1" style="margin-left:112px; border: 2px solid lightblue;">

        <% 
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
                int numOfCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();%>

                <tr>
                <%for(int i = 1; i <= numOfCols; i++){%>

                        <th> <%= rsmd.getColumnName(i)%> </th> 

                <%}%>
                </tr>

                <%while(resultSet.next()){%>
                    <tr>
                    <%for(int i = 1; i <= numOfCols; i++){%>

                        <td> <%= resultSet.getString(i)%> </td> 
                    <%}%>
                    </tr>
                <%}
                }
                resultSet.close();
                statement.close();%>

    </table>
```

Comment: Keep the lines  of code  in finally block. Eg:if((resultSet != null){resultSet.close}..

Comment: did it but same issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862853/resource-leak-warning-in-eclipse -- This should help

Comment: more solutions please