# Broken Pipe - Socket Exception - with latest version of Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I didn't expect to see this even using the latest version of Hibernate. I am using Hibernate version 5.1.0.Final

I am using it with spring and here is the config:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="mySQLDataSource">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="package.to.scan"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="showSql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The mySQLDataSource bean:

```
<bean id="mySQLDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/dbResource"/>
</bean>
```

The JNDI resource:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/dbResource" 
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="50"
    username="root"
    password=""
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"
    />
```

There is probably a workaround this but I am really interested in knowing what is the standard approach to resolve this problem?

Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-mvc] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: ] with root cause
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3333)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4997)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1525)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:338)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.adism.dao.AdDaoImpl.beginTransaction(AdDaoImpl.java:59)
    at com.adism.dao.AdDaoImpl.getAll(AdDaoImpl.java:69)
    at com.adism.web.controllers.AdController.indexPage(AdController.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue is happening if the application has no activity with the database for a considerable amount of time (say 12 hours in your case). So it could be an issue related to expired or stale connection issue.

As per this [link](http://amitcodes.com/2008/07/26/16/), MySQL by defaults assumes any connection that has been idle for a longer period, say 8 hours, marks it as inactive and closes it. But the connection pooling mechanism on application end may not be aware of this connection close and results in broken pipe exception at a later point when the app actually uses it.

As suggested in the link please set up with `testOnBorrow=true` and `validationQuery=SELECT 1`.

Apart from that, your `sessionFactory` is still using hibernate4 specific one.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
```

I believe that could be the issue.

Can you try with hibernate5 specific LocalSessionFactoryBean.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
```

Comment: sure, i will try this, but I will have to come back after some time because this issue happens after some time after the tomcat is restarted

Comment: Hi Madhusudana, I still got this issue!

Comment: @Tefa Looks like you are getting this issue not every time but intermittently. How frequently are you getting this issue? And what is happening to subsequent requests or connections?

Comment: I am getting this problem every time, basically what happens is when I do a fresh deployment or restart tomcat all works fine, this issue happens when there is no hit to site in say e.g. 12 hours and after 12 hours when I hit the site I see that issue.

Comment: @Tefa I suspect it could be an issue related to expired or stale connection issue. Can you please check this URL if that relates to your issue [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046815/connection-pool-issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046815/connection-pool-issue)

Comment: @Tefa Another more related link that indicates that MySQL by defaults assumes any connection that is idle for more than 8 hours as inactive and closes it. But the connection pooling mechanism on application end isn't aware of this connection close and results in broken pipe exception at a later point when it is actually used by the application. Please have a look at [http://amitcodes.com/2008/07/26/16/](http://amitcodes.com/2008/07/26/16/). This looks more relevant, please check.

Comment: Thanks, for now, I have put autoReconnect=true in the url, I already have validationQuery, let me test this and if this doesn't work too then I will try 'testOnBorrow' property to see if that fixes the issue. I will reply after 8 hours lol

Comment: @Tefa hmm I know :) Fingers crossed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103545/discussion-between-tefa-and-madhusudana-reddy-sunnapu).

Comment: @Tefa updated the answer as per the working solution. Glad it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your help Madhu, nice talking to you.