# Connection already closed (oracle 12c only)

Tags: spring, jdbc, oracle12c

We have a Spring Jdbc based project. It runs perfectly fine with Oracle 11g jdbc driver. However, when we recently switches to Oracle 12c, we are constantly seeing the "connection is already closed" exception.

We are wondering what could be causing this issue. We have already configured the "select 1 from dual" as validation SQL and not sure what else could be done.

Is there any analysis tool to see what might be causing this kind of error?

BTW We are using UCP connection pooling.

Comment: Have you configured the datasource to test on borrow? `spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true` http://stackoverflow.com/a/30455408/1199132

Comment: yes we already have it configured to true.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?