# How to reconnect database if the connection closed in spring jpa?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-boot, spring-jpa, mysql in my web application.When my application is running for some hours, I always got below exceptions:

```
2016-07-30 21:27:12.434 ERROR 13553 --- [http-nio-8090-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : No operations allowed after connection closed.
2016-07-30 21:27:12.434  WARN 13553 --- [http-nio-8090-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
2016-07-30 21:27:12.434 ERROR 13553 --- [http-nio-8090-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : No operations allowed after connection closed.
2016-07-30 21:27:12.438 ERROR 13553 --- [http-nio-8090-exec-8] [.[.[.[.c.c.Go2NurseJerseyConfiguration] : Servlet.service() for servlet [com.cooltoo.config.Go2NurseJerseyConfiguration] in context with path [] threw exception [org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement] with root cause

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3119) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar!/:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3570) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar!/:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3559) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar!/:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4110) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar!/:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar!/:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar!/:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar!/:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar!/:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
```

I have checked that the database is running well. I have to restart my spring-boot application when that happened. How can I check what the problem is? Why the database connection got closed? If that happened, whether I can re-connect the database?
Below is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.max-active=150
```

Answer (score 8):

This seems like a common error with MySQL.

**1)** Add this to your application.properties and see how it goes:

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

**testOnBorrow** is detailed in the [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) and this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684807/spring-boot-jpa-configuring-auto-reconnect). I'm however unable to find a reference on **validationQuery** in Spring's doc, but it seems to do the trick.

**2)** Or, you may use **testWhileIdle** as suggested here http://christoph-burmeister.eu/?p=2849

He suggests adding this to your application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

This solution is also mentionned in the other stackoverflow question, it was just not the accepted answer, but seems to be the solution for some.

**3)** In this case, they also added **timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis**:

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 3600000
```

EDIT: Another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451470/connection-to-db-dies-after-424-in-spring-boot-jpa-hibernate) that covers this (with a very complete answer)