# spring-boot:jdbc re-connection after db outage

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-boot

i'm using spring-boot and datasource with jdbc template (postgres). in my service i do

```
@Autowired
public MyDao(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

and later `jdbcTemplate().query(...);`. all works as expected but when i restart db, it stops working. looks like datasource doesn't reconnect. i got:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
```

i got same error when i add:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    testOnBorrow: true
    validationQuery: select 1
```

how to make datasource reconnect automatically?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451470/connection-to-db-dies-after-424-in-spring-boot-jpa-hibernate (although it is about MySQL, the settings apply to other drivers as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually i found it does reconnect after adding:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    testOnBorrow: true
    validationQuery: select 1
```

i just needed to wait the default `validationInterval` that is 30sec

Comment: Can you accept your answer so that the question does not show as unanswered? Thanks!