# MySQL and Spring Boot: lost connections after some interval of inactivity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I faced a problem about connections to MySQL from my Spring Boot application. It works fine for several hours after deploy. But when I stop any activities from my side (often at night) the server falls with the exceptions like below:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.trammellventures.btd.services.user.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e8f85.getAdminAccount(<generated>)
    at com.trammellventures.btd.services.email.EmailCommonService.informAdminAboutTickerDefect(EmailCommonService.java:102)
    at com.trammellventures.btd.services.email.EmailCommonService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bec6b855.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:170)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
> 
The last packet successfully received from the server was 33 715 694 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:981)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3365)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3805)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4874)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:100)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:143)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:173)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2954)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3375)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

My application.properties file is very simple:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

I suppose that it can be connected with MySQL connection timeout (default is 8h if I'm not mistaken). Am I right? Can you provide me some solutions for this situation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the following properties to see if the connection is kepet persistent.

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

See if this helps you [Connection to Db dies after >4<24 in spring-boot jpa hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451470/connection-to-db-dies-after-424-in-spring-boot-jpa-hibernate)

Also please take into account the property change log for spring-boot 1.4 to find your property keys [Spring-Boot.1.4-Changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Configuration-Changelog):

```
spring.datasource.dbcp.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.dbcp.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=3600000
spring.datasource.dbcp.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

All these properties and their configuration meaning can be found here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html