# set autoReconnect=true, can't work in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Getting Exception :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last
>   packet successfully received from the server was 235,873,616
>   milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   235,873,629 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured
>   value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
>   testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing
>   the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the
>   Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this
>   problem. at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

set `autoReconnect=true`, can't work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection to Db dies after >4<24 in spring-boot jpa hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451470/connection-to-db-dies-after-424-in-spring-boot-jpa-hibernate)