# How delete inactive connection to mysql in Spring Boot 1.4.3, Multiple Datasource

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 1.4.3, and i have multiple datasource mysql, sqlserver.

The sqlserver connection is remote and when my backend is in production in the night my backend breaks

The myserver connection is good, the sqlserver connection I'm having problems

I want disconnect after time inactive

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.xxxx" }
        )
    public class remoteDBConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dataSourcexxxx")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bar.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSourcexxxx") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.xxxx")
                .persistenceUnit("xxxx")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManagerxxx")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactorySiconet") EntityManagerFactory
                    entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
```

application.properties

```
bar.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://4354dfgdg.no-ip.org:1433;databaseName=xxxxxx
bar.datasource.username=xxxx
bar.datasource.password=xxxx
bar.datasource.driverClassName= com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
bar.jpa.show-sql=true
bar.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
bar.jpa.hibernspring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
```

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451470/connection-to-db-dies-after-424-in-spring-boot-jpa-hibernate

Comment: thanks, I'm going to wait in the night for check if succes