# Docker MySQL drops tables after timeout: No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, spring-data-jpa

A very weird situation. I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA and MySQL running in a docker container. After starting the application all works fine (the DB is initialized upon startup with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`).

If I leave the app running, after ~10 minutes, when running another request, I get back `table doesn't exist`. Checking the DB, I can see all the tables are gone (the schema is still there)!

Logs show me this WARN right before the error:

```
2020-12-20 16:15:41.151  WARN 11018 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : myDS - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@67dd33b2 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2020-12-20 16:15:41.153  WARN 11018 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : myDS - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@3817c06d (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2020-12-20 16:15:41.155  WARN 11018 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : myDS - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@536cd1b2 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
```

And then:

```
2020-12-20 16:15:41.161  WARN 11018 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2020-12-20 16:15:41.161 ERROR 11018 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'tasker.account' doesn't exist
2020-12-20 16:15:41.173  INFO 11018 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command
```

I've also added this setting in application.properties:

`spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=600000` to match mysql's settings.

Docker is started with:

`docker run --name=mysql1 --restart on-failure -d mysql/mysql-server:8.0`

**Note: This never happens with local instance of mysql (native, not in docker)**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding this setting seems to have solved the problem: `spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=100000` while `spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=600000` which matches exactly the mySQL value, does not work. Therefore it is a combination of this problem and create-drop.

Comment: what is your connection type?

Comment: @Perimosh connection type? Not sure what you mean exactly, but it's jdbc url: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/tasker?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Comment: is it embedded? if it is, is it hsqldb, h2 or derby?

Comment: @Perimosh it is `mysql` running on docker as mentioned in the question. It is not hsqldb, h2 or derby.

Comment: Ok then using create-drop is not good as it is designed for in memory/embedded dbs.

Comment: @Perimosh create drop is designed for creating and dropping the DB every time the app is restarted, regardless of type of DB. It is for development/testing purposes.

Comment: In your case it may fit OK because you have your db inside a container

Answer (score 3):

`create-drop` will drop the schema upon closing the SessionFactory, now let's treat the part of SessionFactory closing , it can be related to network connections timeouting which leads to SessionFactory beeing closed automaticaly by springboot.

You can add a heartbeat to your application.properties to prevent this behaviour from occuring , any way this part has solved so many problems in my production env so it is very helpfull to add this bit:

```
#HeartBeat the database so that connections don't die otherwise the connections die silently
#and when a query commes along the JPA will throw an error and keep throwing errors and a restart of the process
#is inevitable
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

I will put here link to an answer that deals with checking connections and pool health [Connection to Db dies after >4<24 in spring-boot jpa hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451470/connection-to-db-dies-after-424-in-spring-boot-jpa-hibernate)

An other thing since this is just a dev envrionement you can change `create-drop` to `create` which configures springboot to drop existing schema and create a new one at the startup of your springboot app this way the schema will never get destroyed when connection is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer:

[How does spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property exactly work in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring)

As you're using `create-drop`, your probably interested in the following section of his answer:

> Typically in test case scenarios, you'll likely use `create-drop` so
> that you create your schema, your test case adds some mock data, you
> run your tests, and then during the test case cleanup, the schema
> objects are dropped, leaving an empty database.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer the question why the app is still running and the database gets erased after a timeout of 10 minutes. I am using `create-drop` for running the app in develop mode locally, it's not part of any automated tests. I start the app, it times out, the data disappears, but the app continues to run

Comment: The value `create-drop` gets passed to Hibernate, where it is understood as follows: "The database schema will be dropped and created afterward. Upon closing the SessionFactory, the database schema will be dropped." -- I would say your SessionFactory gets closed after a while. Can you put a breakpoint there and look if that happens?

Comment: Just another page trying to explain the use of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` showing that tables get dropped at `SessionFactory#close()`: https://javausecase.com/2017/09/03/hibernate-5-hbm2ddl-auto-explained/

Comment: You may also check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: Please note that keeping the old timeout value and only changing `create-drop` to `create` doesn't solve the problem. The same happens - the tables get dropped

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be in this setting:

`spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime`

Adding this setting in application.properties seems to have solved the problem: `spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=100000` while `spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=600000` which matches exactly the mySQL value, does not work - i.e. results in tables being dropped.