# How to use Java JDBC connection pool?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

I want to use a JDBC connection pool. The most important factor is that it's easy-to-use and bug-free. What is suitable for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another fine alternative is the [Apache Database Connection Pool](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/).

Instead of getting a connection using DriverManager, you'll use a JNDI naming service to get your connection out of the pool.

Be sure to close your resources - Connection, Statement, and ResultSet.  If you don't, your pool will be quickly exhausted.

Answer (score 8):

Also have a look at [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com); there are some samples on the site.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html) (over DBCP which has some really [serious issues](http://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&pid=12310469&sorter/field=issuekey&sorter/order=DESC&status=1&status=4)): it works great<strike>, is actively maintained</strike> and easy to use. Maybe have a look at this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0) for more inputs on this.

**Update:** I admit I didn't check the status when I wrote this answer (I'm using c3p0 for many years and was happy with it) and it appears that c3p0 development is in stand by. Funnily, the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0) mentioned as reference has been updated the 2010-03-12 to mention that DBCP development is alive again. My original post may thus be out of date.

Comment: Is c3p0 really actively maintained? The latest version is 0.9.1.2 from 2007-05-21.

Comment: @Arne Damn, you're right. And DBCP has been resurrected. I've updated my answer...

Answer (score 3):

I've used this [MiniConnectionPoolManager](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/8.htm) with [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) and [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/).

Answer (score 1):

2 years later...
Just migrated to [jdbc-pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) (standard on Tomcat 7 now) it was very easy to implement it standalone in a web app or for the the whole server. Per specifications and my experience it out-performs c3p0.

Per specs it is also alot cleaner than dbcp or c3p0.