# Connection Pooling in Java SE?

Tags: java, connection-pooling

It is hard to find a resource on this without finding Java EE, but here is what I am looking for:

All I have is a standard Java SE app, it makes a lot of DB connections. I simply need to make use of a connection pool. Any suggestions?

Comment: How else does one connect to a database using Java?

Comment: JDBC drivers all use sockets to do the low level reading/writing of data to the DB. Only a nut would do it this way if a JDBC driver is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0). There is also this other question which discusses [c3p0 vs DBCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0) and several stand-alone connection pools.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options that don't require any Java EE:

[C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html) - I have used this pool library for a long time in a Java SE app but it does not support the new Java 6 JDBC interfaces.  You can still use the pool Java 6 but if you try and call any of the new methods an exception is thrown saying that the method is not implemented.

[DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) - I have never used this connection pool myself but I have seen various posts about it, and it does support the new JDBC features added in Java 6

Comment: In DBCP everything is synchronized to a single thread. If your app is multiuser/multithreaded, C3P0 is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Can I also suggest BoneCP (http://jolbox.com) ? It is currently the fastest connection pool available and offers a good feature set.

Comment: It looks like [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1662916/311525) you now feel that there is another connection pool which is faster.

Answer (score 2):

javax.sql.DataSource provides a connection pool, and most DB vendors provide an implementation of DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of [Java connection pool libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/connection-pools). I have only used c3po out of these, as part of Hibernate, and so far it works fine (as much as I actually see of it... but I guess if I rarely ever notice the connection pooling software I am using, then it is working well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).  Even BoneCP's author [admits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662916/311525) it is now the king of the hill.