# Should ResultSetMapper implementations be thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, jdbi

I have been trying to fold multiple rows within the same ResultSetMapper, i have a  `Map<String, MappedObj> map` which i simply use to fold multiple rows to the same object as,

```
public MappedObj map(final int index, final ResultSet r, final StatementContext ctx) {
   MappedObj mappedObj = map.get(r.getString("Id"));
   if (mappedObj!=null){
      mappedObj.addValue(r.getString("RowToFold"));
   } else {
      mappedObj = new MappedObj();
      // Mapping
      map.put(mappedObj.getId(), mappedObj);
   }
   return mappedObj;
}
```

My concern is that, if ResultSetMapper::map is called in parallel, this code will break. From jdbi Query, i see that it is not called in parallel, however i am not sure if it means it is safe to implement them non thread-safe. Is my approach safe to use?

This is actually a general question. What is the default thread safety assumption on an interface implementation if it is not documented?

Comment: Duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794167/is-resultset-thread-safe#:~:text=No%2C%20ResultSet%20should%20not%20be,in%20which%20it%20was%20created.

Comment: @StijnHaezebrouck Not a duplicate. This is asking about a transformer that is applied _to_ a `ResultSet`.

Comment: There is no _general_ default assumption, but operations like this that are really functions should properly be stateless and thus thread-safe.