# Setup Connection Pooling in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, connection-pooling

How can I setup connection pooling in Spring MVC? I am working on an intranet website powered by Spring MVC 2.5 and jQuery. This is my first attempt at web development.

I am not sure but, I am only using this in my spring configuration file and I saw this in the Spring MVC step By Step tutorial

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
   <list>
    <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

This looks good during development and connection speed is fast but I am not sure if this will still holds true if many users are concurrently connected.

How can I achieve this? I have read that this is not an optimal connection datasource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html), which has some powerful configuration and optimization available.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="..." />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="..." />
    <property name="user" value="..." />
    <property name="password" value="..." />
</bean>
```

Comment: As a new Spring Developer, I havent heard about this C3PO thing.  But as I googled the net, I found some interesting discussion about this.  One question though to clear my thoughts,  If I create a bean like the one you have given above and then add the required C3PO jar file in my build path, can I say say that I am doing connection pooling already?  Thanks

Comment: "If I create a bean like the one you have given above and then add the required C3PO jar file in my build path, can I say say that I am doing connection pooling already?"

Yes you can, though you could say the same with BasicDataSource (it uses commons-pool).

Answer (score 1):

Your current setup is correct, all you need to do in order to use basic connection pooling is use a DataSource implementation provided by a connection pooling library, in your case [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/).  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0) for a few links to other alternatives, C3P0 being one of them.

Note that when you actually use the DataSource bean you're injecting wrap it in a [SimpleJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html) or use [DataSourceUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html) to obtain a Connection - see [Spring JDBC Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
For connection Pooling

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

//Add this two more parameters
   <property name="**initialSize**" value="20" />
   <property name="**maxActive**" value="30" />


 </bean>

connection pool will create 20 database connection as initialSize is 20 and goes up to 30 Database connection if required as maxActive is 30.
```