# Tomcat JDBC connection pool VS c3p0 Connection pool

Tags: java, tomcat, connection, connection-pooling, c3p0

I recently came across this connection pool implementation.

http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html

I find it quite interesting.

Did anyone try this out? I think it looks great except the fact that it does not support automatic retry and statement cache like c3p0.

Does anyone one know how it compares to c3p0?

Till now I used c3p0 but I find it's connection handling in a multi-thread environment problematic. It opens way too much connections compared to number of application threads.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I've used it in one of my projects and it works great.

I can think of only one online article which compares Tomcat pool to C3P0: [tomcatexpert.com](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/03/22/understanding-jdbc-pool-performance-improvements). The C3P0 benches are however pretty off, their excuse was that they couldn't configure it to its max on Tomcat.

I'd say, for the most reliable data, just give it a try and bench yourself. I did and it satisfied me.

#### See also:

- [Connection pooling options with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0)