# SQLException w/ Tomcat 7.0 JDBC connection pool and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I'm trying to use the new Tomcat 7.0 JDBC connection pool and MySql. It says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0) that you can drop the latest tomcat-jdbc.jar into your tomcat/lib directory in a Tomcat 6.0 environment, and that's what I've done.

I'm using Spring to initialize and instantiate the DataSource per examples around the web:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close" 
p:driverClassName="${driver_class}"
p:url="${url}"
p:username="${username?root}"
p:password="${password}"
p:initialSize="10"
p:initSQL="SELECT DTS FROM DT_TM_TS FOR READ ONLY WITH UR"
p:minIdle="10"
p:maxIdle="100"
p:maxActive="100"
p:maxWait="6000"
p:jmxEnabled="true"
p:jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
p:removeAbandoned="true"
p:removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
p:logAbandoned="true"
p:testOnBorrow="true"
p:testOnReturn="false"
p:testWhileIdle="false"
p:useEquals="false"
p:fairQueue="false"
p:timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
p:minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
p:validationInterval="1800000"
p:validationQuery="SELECT DTS FROM DT_TM_TS FOR READ ONLY WITH UR"
/>
```

However when I try to connect to the db it throws this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:243)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:176)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:647)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:452)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1325)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:529)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:495)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:236)
    ... 59 more
```

I've got mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar in both the webapp WEB-INF/lib and tomcat/lib. I can connect fine specifying the driver details in persistence.xml (no DataSource/connection pooling).

Comment: did you also update `factory` attribute in `resource` tag (definition of datasource). besides, this stack trace does not look like it is complete (is it?).

Comment: No, the DataSource isn't being created by Tomcat's DataSourceFactory it's being created by Spring. BTW I am now running in a Tomcat 6 web container and the problem remains.

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a very simple workaround with Spring. Instead of having the Tomcat connection pool create the database connection and fail because of class loader shenanigans, let Spring create it and pass a reference to the connection pool.

```
<!-- Data source template for use in the connection pool. -->
<bean id="dataSourceTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- Connection pool as data source. -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- Refer to a separately created bean as a data source template to work around a quirk of Tomcat's class loader. -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceTemplate" />
    ...
</bean>
```

Then the connection pool will actually use the database connection as a template for creating as many additional connections as it needs.

The best part is that you don't have to mess with tomcat/lib, which you may not even have access to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Spring 3.1, Hibernate 4.0, VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition 2.6.1 with Tomcat 7.0.20.B and Maven 3. Having the connector managed by Maven I encountered the same issue.

Infact reading the [manual](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) I've found

> driverClassName
>
> (String) The fully qualified Java class name of the
>   JDBC driver to be used. **The driver has to be accessible from the same
>   classloader as tomcat-jdbc.jar**

So I resolved by adding the mysql connector (mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar) in the lib directory of Tomcat (vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.1.RELEASE/tomcat-7.0.20.B.RELEASE/lib) and setting in Maven the scope of the connector package to provided.

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat 6.0 I need to put my JDBC drivers into common/lib/**ext**

But the search path for that is configured in catalina.properties check out the property `common.loader` in there. Make sure that common/lib is listed there.

Comment: This has been changed between Tomcat 5.5 and Tomcat 6.0. There's no `/common` anymore in 6.0. The `common.loader` of 6.0 defaults to `${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar` which is perfectly fine and indicates that you need to drop JARs in `/lib`.