# Java thread dump: `WAITING (on object monitor)` line not followed by `waiting on <0x1234>` line

Tags: multithreading, jvm, thread-dump

My thread `TP-Processor27` is waiting, tells me a thread dump.

Usually `WAITING (on object monitor)` lines are immediately followed by a `waiting on <0x09c34480>` or similar line. But not in the dump below. In such cases, can I know on which id is the wait?

```
"TP-Processor27" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aab91c88800 nid=0x58d7 in Object.wait() [0x0000000050d01000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1104)
        - locked <0x00002aaaccce0150> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool.borrowObject(AbandonedObjectPool.java:88)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:115)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1053)
[...]

"TP-Processor28" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aab91c8a000 nid=0x58d8 runnable [0x0000000050e03000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
[...]
```

Comment: What functional problem are you seeing? Are there any threads, waiting to lock?

Comment: I would like to know on what `TP-Processor27` is waiting. Usually there is an id showing what object is being waited on, but here no info...

Comment: The dbcp might have a bug, see this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714511/deadlock-issue-in-dbcp-deployed-on-tomcat

Comment: You may have to tune some dataSource parameters. Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714511/deadlock-issue-in-dbcp-deployed-on-tomcat/46420093#46420093

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I saw a problem where there is actually no problem.