# How to get the on object monitor address when the java.lang.Thread.State in BLOCKED?

Tags: jvm

We found a blocking issue for a application, and from the stack dump  we found that many of the threads (one of which is catalina-exec-998 ) were blocked by thread catalina-exec-995 through the lock 0x000000065888b918, and we also found the blocker thread catalina-exec-995 is also in the state BLOCKED, it seems it tried to obtain the object monitor which was already owned by the other thread, however in the stack call there is no information for what object monitor address  it tried to wait on,

so my question is how to find which object monitor\lock **address** it wait on?
Also BTW how to prevent object monitor from being JIT-compiled to make wait info always available by JVM option -XX:CompileCommand?

BTW, I also found a similar issue in [java-thread-dump-waiting-on-object-monitor-what-is-it-waiting-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701740/java-thread-dump-waiting-on-object-monitor-what-is-it-waiting-on/), and from the JVM Expert's answer I know the missing "waiting on " information maybe caused by the JIT  compiler, and the solution in that URL is just suitable for Object.wait() in a synchronized object, however my situation is obviously different, as it tried to get object monitor instead of waiting for getting notification from the synchronized object.

The following information is the call stack for two threads mentioned about:

```
"catalina-exec-995" #1178 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6b7831f000 nid=0x15c0 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f6b43ffc000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:308)
- locked <**0x000000065888b918**> (a java.util.jar.JarFile)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:240)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:223)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourcesInternal(StandardRoot.java:327)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResources(CachedResource.java:124)
- locked <0x000000068aa3c7a0> (a org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResources(Cache.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResources(StandardRoot.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResources(StandardRoot.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:939)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1142)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.getResources(ServiceFinder.java:352)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.access$200(ServiceFinder.java:159)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$AbstractLazyIterator.setConfigs(ServiceFinder.java:720)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$AbstractLazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:732)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.toClassArray(ServiceFinder.java:595)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:318)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:311)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:159)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initWriters(MessageBodyFactory.java:207)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:163)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:342)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:118)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:191)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:187)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:187)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:170)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:679)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.util.RestfulUtils.request(RestfulUtils.java:33)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.util.RestfulUtils.requestGet(RestfulUtils.java:28)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.util.PaWebUtils.validatePaToken(PaWebUtils.java:344)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.sso.PaSSO.readUserToken(PaSSO.java:137)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.filter.UserLoginFilter.validatePortalLogin(UserLoginFilter.java:190)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.filter.UserLoginFilter.onAccessDenied(UserLoginFilter.java:248)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter.onAccessDenied(AccessControlFilter.java:133)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter.onPreHandle(AccessControlFilter.java:162)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.PathMatchingFilter.isFilterChainContinued(PathMatchingFilter.java:203)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.PathMatchingFilter.preHandle(PathMatchingFilter.java:178)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:131)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.filter.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.filter.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:41)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
- locked <0x0000000612c3a940> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- <0x000000062d3e9728> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)


"catalina-exec-998" #1181 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6b7c359800 nid=0x15c3 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f6b43cf9000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:308)
- waiting to lock <**0x000000065888b918**> (a java.util.jar.JarFile)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:240)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:223)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourcesInternal(StandardRoot.java:327)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResources(CachedResource.java:124)
- locked <0x0000000691ae3b90> (a org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResources(Cache.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResources(StandardRoot.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResources(StandardRoot.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:939)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1142)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.getResources(ServiceFinder.java:352)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.access$200(ServiceFinder.java:159)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$AbstractLazyIterator.setConfigs(ServiceFinder.java:720)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$AbstractLazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:732)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.toClassArray(ServiceFinder.java:595)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:318)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:311)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:159)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initWriters(MessageBodyFactory.java:207)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:163)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:342)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:118)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:191)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:187)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:187)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:170)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:679)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.util.RestfulUtils.request(RestfulUtils.java:33)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.util.RestfulUtils.requestGet(RestfulUtils.java:28)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.util.PaWebUtils.validatePaToken(PaWebUtils.java:344)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.filter.UserLoginFilter.keepPaTokenInCookie(UserLoginFilter.java:496)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.filter.UserLoginFilter.isAccessAllowed(UserLoginFilter.java:448)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter.onPreHandle(AccessControlFilter.java:162)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.PathMatchingFilter.isFilterChainContinued(PathMatchingFilter.java:203)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.PathMatchingFilter.preHandle(PathMatchingFilter.java:178)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:131)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.filter.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.meritdata.tempo.foundation.security.filter.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:41)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
- locked <0x0000000612c9dee0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- <0x000000062ca8ffc8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `catalina-exec-995` and `catalina-exec-998` threads compete for the same object monitor - an instance of `JarFile` with the address `0x000000065888b918`. The stacktrace already has all the information.

You might have been confused by the fact that both threads are in `BLOCKED` state while one of them is `waiting to lock` the monitor, and the other has `locked` this monitor. This is absolutely normal situation: acquiring object monitor and switching thread state does not happen atomically.

A thread that is waiting to enter an object monitor *first* aquires the lock *and then* swiches from `BLOCKED` to `RUNNABLE` state. When you take a thread dump in between you may catch exactly the situation you see.

Let me demonstrate this with a simple example.

```
public class Sync implements Runnable {
    int n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sync sync = new Sync();
        new Thread(sync, "Sync1").start();
        new Thread(sync, "Sync2").start();
        new Thread(sync, "Sync3").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            inc();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void inc() {
        n++;
    }
}
```

A thread dump may look like

```
"Sync3" #13 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001deab800 nid=0x25d4 runnable [0x000000001e98f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at Sync.run(Sync.java:13)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Sync2" #12 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001deab000 nid=0x230c waiting for monitor entry [0x000000001e88f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at Sync.inc(Sync.java:18)
    - locked <0x000000076b8a1108> (a Sync)
    at Sync.run(Sync.java:13)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Sync1" #11 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001deaa000 nid=0x16d4 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000001e78f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at Sync.inc(Sync.java:18)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000076b8a1108> (a Sync)
    at Sync.run(Sync.java:13)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Obviously, there is just one object monitor - the single instance of `Sync`. Both `Sync1` and `Sync2` threads are `BLOCKED`, but one of them is `waiting to lock`, and the other has `locked` the monitor.

Comment: Very appreciated for your clearly clarification, do it mean releasing object monitor and switching thread state also does not happen atomically? That is to say, it is possible that the thread already releasing the lock , however it's state still in runnable ,but trying to wait to lock?

Comment: BTW,if the "waiting on" information missing caused by the JIT compiler for object monitor(just like the situation for object.wait), can we  prevent it by using  JVM XX:CompileCommand="exclude,package/Sync.inc"?

Comment: @YuFengShen *"releasing object monitor and switching thread state also does not happen atomically"* - Yes, but in this case the order is reverse.

Comment: *"if the "waiting on" information missing caused by the JIT compiler for object monitor"* - This is not the case when entering/leaving synchronized block.

Comment: I am very admire for your incredible knowledge of the JVM. Thank you very much.