# Using tomcat's connection pool with JPA

Tags: tomcat, jpa

I want to use connection pool with JPA/TopLink in my web app running on tomcat.Earlier I use jdbc's Connection and Statement classes to manipulate data in database; to use connection pool in that way I simply declare resource in context.xml and get this resource in application:

```
Context c = new InitialContext();
DataSource source = (DataSource) ((Context)c.lookup("java:comp/env")).lookup("jdbc/MySource");
```

And now I want to use such connection pool with JPA. How can i do this?

One more question: I've seen in some examples that the reosurce is declared in context.xml and then it is declared in web.xml in < resource-ref>. Why I should declare it in different places or is it the same declaration, I mean is it an equivalent of declaration in context.xml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *And now I want to use such connection pool with JPA. How can i do this?*

Assuming that you've already declared the connection pooled datasource creation by `<Resource>` in a `context.xml`, then you just need to declare the datasource usage for JPA in the webapp's `/META-INF/persistence.xml`.

```
<persistence-unit name="YourPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/MySource</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

---

> *One more question: I've seen in some examples that the reosurce is declared in `context.xml` and then it is declared in `web.xml` in `<resource-ref>`. Why I should declare it in different places or is it the same declaration, I mean is it an equivalent of declaration in `context.xml`?*

The `<Resource>` one in `context.xml` definies the **creation** of the datasource by the servletcontainer. It can be used by multiple webapps. The `<resource-ref>` one in `web.xml` definies the **usage** of the datasource by the particular webapp. Note: when using JPA, you don't need the one in `web.xml`. It goes into `persistence.xml`.

Comment: So, if I define < resource> in context.xml and don't define <resource-ref > in web.xml, will I be able to use the pooled connections or it simply will create new connection each time when I fetch the data from db?

Comment: The Tomcat datasource uses by default the builtin DBCP datasource which is a connection pool already. You can however change it by altering the `factory` parameter in `<Resource>`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0/3481821#3481821

Comment: @BalusC How can we get Entitymanager From Datasource......because I Have heard we cant do connection pooling with JPA in tomcat since its not a JEE server and I am uisng JPA utill class from which i am getting entitymanager... :)