# How do I properly destroy an Apache Commons DBCP Pool in Java?

Tags: java, memory-management, connection-pooling, apache-commons, apache-commons-dbcp

I would like to use a PoolingDataSource as my connection pool (API at: http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/PoolingDataSource.html), but I don't know what to do with the pool when I no longer need it.  What if I want to connect to a new database and don't need the connections in the old pool anymore?  There is no close method on the pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to kill this pool to create a new one.

You can manage the connections in it using the maxIdle, timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis and minEvictableIdleTimeMillis parameters (see [here](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html)) to ensure idle connections get closed in a reasonable time.

Or you can configure a [GenericObjectPool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/api-1.5.4/index.html?org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html) with those parameters programatically and use when creating your PoolingDataSource.  That has a close() method if you want to force it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not answering your question directly, but may I recommend *not* using DBCP? It has had a number of serious problems, which other libraries learned from and improved upon.

There are [much better pools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520585/3474) out there.

Comment: While fairly accurate; it should be noted DBCP has been actively maintained since this answer was provided.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of pool are you using? If you're using the [AbandonedObjectPool](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/AbandonedObjectPool.html), then that's a subclass of Commons Pool's [GenericObjectPool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html), which has a [close()](http://commons.apache.org/pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#close%28%29) method.

Comment: I am using a PoolingDataSource as I said in the question.  I also linked to it's API docs.