# java call function after every 20hrs in backend

Tags: java, mysql, timer

i need to invoke a mysql connection and make a dummy query after every 20hrs to the connections present so that the connections doesnot get closed. Here i need a call to function( this function implements a connection and a dummy query) that independently be running the in backend. please suggest the timers functions that run in background and invoke the function after every 20hrs..

Comment: If you're going so long without making a query such that it closes the connection, why don't you just keep the connection closed unless you need it?

Comment: i am keeping the connections in pool.i am reusing the old connections instead of closing and creating new one which is a cost effective then reusing. so thats why i need a timer function. i will try ur suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer to your question, but a useful tip:

Do not use a dummy query to fire every 20 hours to keep mysql connection keep alive. Better to go with ***connection pool*** technique. I will suggest you to use `c3p0`.

For more help see this discussion: [Connection pooling options with JDBC: DBCP vs C3P0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0)

Comment: @Jasonw: Yes, BoneCP is also an alternative.+1. [BoneCP WebSite](http://jolbox.com/)

Comment: with bonecp or c3p0 you can specify a validationQuery like 'SELECT 1' to keep up the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Do you  mean like this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

```
int delay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 20; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

You can also use an operating system scheduler (like "cron" on Linux, or Task Mgr on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). It is an enerprise job scheduler.

The advantages for using quatz are:

- You do not have to care about task or thread development
- You need to develop solely the methods which need to be invoked on a timed basis
- You configure schedules etc. with defined and documented property files

Disadvantages are

- You introduce overhead

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Timer can schedule events at pre-defined periods (like the timer mentioned by paulsm4 but no need to involve SWING/AWT).