# What pooled data source should I use for Spring 3.1.0, Hibernate 4.0.1.Final, and MySQL 5.1?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I'm using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.0.1.Final, and MySQL 5.1.  What is the pooled data source I should be using?  I'm currently using (snippet from application context file) ...

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproj</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>myproj</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>password</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but this isn't a pooled data source, creating JDBC connections on each call.  I used to have this Hibernate config (hibernate.cfg.xml) ...

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproj</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myproj</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    ...
```

but because of a bug in Spring 3.1.0, I can't use a hibernate.cfg.xml file when configuring my session factory bean (which I tried to do like this -- snippet from the spring application context file ...)

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">
    <property name="configLocation"> 
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value> 
    </property>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Apache DBCP, which should be a drop in replacement  something like this:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/> 
    <property name="minIdle" value="5"/> 
    <!-- SELECT 1 is a simple query that returns 1 row in MySQL -->
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/> 
</bean>
```

a few things to note

- you can configure max number of connections.
- you can configure min number of idle connections.
- a query that will get executed to validate the connection is still valid.

Further options exist to configure when validation happens.

Comment: Now org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use something mature and [performant](http://jolbox.com/benchmarks.html) (e.g. not Apache DBCP), use [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/).

Here are the options you can tweak:

```
<!-- BoneCP configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
   <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/yourdb" />
   <property name="username" value="root"/>
   <property name="password" value="abcdefgh"/>
   <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"/>
   <property name="idleMaxAge" value="240"/>
   <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="30"/>
   <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="10"/>
   <property name="partitionCount" value="3"/>
   <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
   <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
   <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
</bean>
```

BoneCP [forum](http://jolbox.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3&sid=d6d8e62d14cc7762b296708274ef9ea9) is very active, and committers are quite responsive.

Another one you can look at (would hear about) is [C3PO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/), although BoneCP performs *a lot* better.

Answer (score 2):

Apache DBCP is a widely used pool. But **do not use** its option `testWhileIdle`. When enabled, It's background evictor thread locks all new connections serving while checking dead connections. It's unacceptable in any non-toy environment. Besides this, we have no problems with it.

You may read more about pools in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0), but keep in mind, that all flames about "fastest pool" only make sense with specific tuning under specific load.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it depends on your application.

There are below conditions(taken from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html)):

1. For test or standalone environments outside of a J2EE container, use `DriverManagerDataSource`
2. For use in a J2EE container, it is recommended to use a `JNDI DataSource`
   provided by the container.
3. For use of a connection pool datasource outside of a J2EE container, consider
   Apache's Jakarta `Commons DBCP` or `C3P0`.