# Quartz scheduler - each time new jdbc connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

I have problem with Quartz Scheduler and configuration for database. Every time scheduler check if new job exist is created new JDBC connections. How to avoid create new connection ?

```
2015-06-19 10:42:05,522 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:142 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8]
2015-06-19 10:42:05,544 DEBUG LocalDataSourceJobStore:3182 - Found 0 triggers that missed their scheduled fire-time.
2015-06-19 10:42:05,545 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2015-06-19 10:42:07,522 DEBUG LocalDataSourceJobStore:3933 - MisfireHandler: scanning for misfires...
2015-06-19 10:42:07,522 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:142 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8]
2015-06-19 10:42:07,539 DEBUG LocalDataSourceJobStore:3182 - Found 0 triggers that missed their scheduled fire-time.
2015-06-19 10:42:07,539 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

And configuration

```
<bean id="scheduler" name="scheduler"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>

            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">USER_JOBS</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">
                org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
            </prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">false</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">20000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">2000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

and datasource, the same for hibernate and quartz scheduler

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You should use a pooled datasource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745165/what-pooled-data-source-should-i-use-for-spring-3-1-0-hibernate-4-0-1-final-an

Comment: @Jens I think this is actually answer to this Q.. Added something in my brain too. thanks..

Answer (score 4):

As far as I see you use `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` class as data source. According to the javadoc it creates jdbc connection every time someone call `getConnection`. I'm sure Quartz call this method internally.

To solve problem you should use pooled DataSource. For example, c3p0 (Look at `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`)

Comment: I used org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource and its working too, thanks anyway : )

Comment: I think c3p0 is more production ready than Apache DBCP. Anyway, feel free to choose most comfortable library )

Comment: @NechaevSergey, DBCP guys have now came up with DNCP2, which is more powerful and robust I think