# Arval SQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already in postgres

Tags: java, linux, postgresql

I am using a database in PostgreSQL 9.1,in which entry are coming continuously from another program . I am sending request from Ajax after 6 sec to fetch the latest entry.tomcat output window shows exception---

```
Arval SQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
```

and program is working correctly also after this.
  When i check my postgres with query---

```
select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;
```

it shows that connection are increasing continuously but I close the connection after each request.I am using netbeans and struts 1.3.

```
     long previousSNO = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("previousSNO"));
    if(previousSNO == 0)
    {
        sb.append("SELECT sno,search_type,search_value,search_date FROM log_temp ORDER BY search_date DESC LIMIT 20");
        prest = cb.executeSQLQuery(sb.toString());
        rs = prest.executeQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        sb.append("SELECT sno,search_type,search_value,search_date FROM log_temp WHERE sno > ? ORDER BY search_date DESC");
        prest = cb.executeSQLQuery(sb.toString());    
        prest.setLong(1, previousSNO);
        rs = prest.executeQuery();
    }
    rs.last();
    int c = rs.getRow();
    rs.beforeFirst();

    if(rs!=null && c>0)
    {    
    //code for making json resultsb from resultset here    
    rs.close();
    }
    cb.closeConnection();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().print(resultsb.toString());
```

//and close method in connection bean is

```
    public void closeConnection() {
    try {
        // st.close();
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("con is closed");
        conn = null;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.getMessage();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("con is not closed");
    }
}
```

Every time its print on console " con is closed";

Comment: Sounds like there is a resource leak somewhere else.

Comment: i suppose this is a more descriptive answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584211/1531476

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [increase the max_connections](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html) in postgres, that is not the solution though. You have resource leaks. It could be any - connection not closed, result set not closed. Please go back and check the code.

Consider using a connection pooling library like [c3p0/BoneCp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0)

A general discussion on [connection pooling is here](http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/JDBC.htm)
(Thanks to @sinisa229 mihajlovski)

Comment: It also depends on the way resources are handled, its good to use connection pool for reusing connections. If a new connection is opened on each call it can still lead to too many connections being opened.

Comment: I am making a new connection for each call and closed it but i think that Postgres is not destroy that connection. I have set connection limit to 100.

Comment: @vikas malik: I doubt. Please post output from select * from pg_stat_activity; It will show the current query, could give a hint to you on where the leak is happening.

Comment: Jayan I checked.In current query field the entry is <IDLE> 99 times. Before 99 connection it doesn't show error but after this it show the error. After 6sec there is a new entry in pg_stat_activity.

Comment: @vikasmalik. please add relevant code to the question. We use postgresql , I am sure it does not have trivial bugs.

Comment: @vikasmalik. Please post to the question. Comment becomes unreadable with such large code.  Where are you closing the connection, result set etc

Comment: @ vikas malik : You could give more details.  Without much details, it is safe to assume the error is in your code.

Answer (score 21):

To increase the connection limit you may like the following document.

This solution is tested on ubuntu 12.04.

**1. Make following changes in postgresql.conf file :**

Open `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf`

```
max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 100MB
max_files_per_process = 100
```

Reference: [shared_buffers size should be less than shmmax size.](http://gabe.grayum.name/?p=postgres_max_connections_and_shared_buffers)

**2. Commands to check shmmax:**

```
$ sysctl -e kernel.shmmax
$ ipcs -l
```

Reference: [Adjusting shmmax and shmall](https://serverfault.com/questions/341680/postgresql-performance-adjusting-shmmax-and-shmall)

**3. Increase the size of shmmax:**

Run the following command:

```
$ sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=134217728
$ sysctl -w kernel.shmall=2097152
```

and write on top in `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
kernel.shmmax=134217728
kernel.shmall=2097152
```

Reference : [SHMMAX in Ubuntu](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/shmmax-in-ubuntu-860206/)

**4. Restart postgresql**

```
$ service postgresql restart
```

**Links:**

http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/Tidbits/perf.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-resource.html

Comment: I set the shared_buffers to 10MB on my mac