# Pentaho BI Server load test - Possible deadlock

Tags: pentaho

We are conducting a load testing on our BI infrastructure at the moment. We are testing with **10 concurrent users** against single pentaho node (bi server platform).

A test scenario for each user is:

1. Open pentaho page
2. Authenticate to the platform
3. Open a report using URL (like this http://itrac5125:8080/pentaho/api/repos/%3Ahome%3ALoadTesting%3A4Measures.xanalyzer/editor)
4. When report is refreshed go to 3) and open another report

As you see steps 3. and 4. are in the loop.

After 15 minutes of running this test the **BI platform becomes extremely unresponsive**. It takes almost three minutes to load home page. Once loaded, trying to push buttons like Browse Files / Create nnw did not result in any change of view.

We used a java profiler tool to what's happening inside application and discovered **200 http threads** (see Threads) attachment. Around 95% of them were for the majority of time blocked **waiting for a resource** (see Blocked). **Is this normal?** I am afraid that managing this amount of threads that are waiting for a resource might be quite an overhead for processor. We checked code of BI platform (see Code) and there is indeed a lock on a resource, that judging by number of threads waiting inside this method seems to be recalculated very often.

Threads (http://postimg.org/image/4c2yug17f/full/)
[image: Threads]
Blocked (http://postimg.org/image/gm32nbd29/)
[image: Blocked]
Code (http://postimg.org/image/6p5vt1b6r/)
[image: Code]

Attaching as well cpu and ram usage graphs that were taken for the time period when the test was executed. 
CPU (http://postimg.org/image/tbxubog6b/full/): [image: CPU]
RAM (http://postimg.org/image/jecpimes9/full/): [image: RAM]

**Is there anyone experiencing similar issues? I would be happy to hear about other experience in terms of load testing / load optimazing for Pentaho BI Server.**

Comment: I had such slowing down issue due to not handling DB connections properly. Refer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296047/too-many-connections-created-in-postgres-when-creating-a-dashboard-in-pentaho

Comment: Hi thanks for comment, we are already using JNDI datasource from tomcat. I don't think the issue lays on database connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After over a week of testing it turned out to be an issue on Pentaho side related to wrong synchronization of threads that lead to a deadlock.

We have been able to contact with Pentaho and they confirmed it is a bug on their side (see jira: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-12642). This should be fixed in a service pack for Pentaho 5.4.