# How to change max_connections for Postgres through SQL command

Tags: postgresql

We have a hosted PostgreSQL, with no access to the system or *.conf files.

I do have a admin access and can connect to it using Oracle SQL developer.
Can I run any command to increase the max_connections. All other parameters seems to be ok shared mem and buffers can hold more connections so there is not problem there.

Comment: `alter system`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html

Comment: I dont get to use that command on a hosted postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the hosted Postgres we are using does not provide this option. (compose.io)

So the work around is to use a pgbouncer to manage you connections better.

Answer (score 48):

Changing `max_connection` parameter needs a Postgres **restart**

Commands

1. Check max_connection just to keep current value in mind

   ```
   SHOW max_connections;
   ```
2. Change max_connection value

   ```
   ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections TO '500';
   ```
3. Restart PostgreSQL server

Comment: I had done step 2 without restarting recently and it bit me.