# Docker-compose: Postgres increase maximum connections

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I keep getting `remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections` errors when I run `postgres:latest` in Docker with Docker Compose.

How can I increase the maximum connections Postgres allows with Docker-Compose?

Note: This is not about Postgres alone, but rather how to pass the values to the official Postgres image on Docker.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the configuration file used by your postgresql image: https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#database-configuration

The parameter you want to change is: `max_connections`, you will find more information about it here : [How to increase the max connections in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778015/how-to-increase-the-max-connections-in-postgres)

Comment: The documentation above refers to mounting a custom `postgresql.conf` file with the desired modified `max_connections` and `shared_buffers` value, or alternatively set them directly on the run line, e.g. `docker run -d --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres -c shared_buffers=256MB -c max_connections=200`