# hive + too many connection to PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, ambari, ulimit

We have ambari cluster with Hadoop version – 2.6.4

When we run query in order to verify connections in PostgreSQL DB , we found many **hive** connection – in our case around 90

***This cause other application problems***

So we suspect that hiveserver2 is not cleaning up connections like it should and files are not being released.

Any suggestion why hive is with a lot connection? to postgresql ? ,
And what is the solution for that?

One option that we found is to update the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` ( according to the answer in the link

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/48351/hiveserver2-hive-users-nofile-ulimit-above-64000.html )

other interesting post is from - https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/48351/hiveserver2-hive-users-nofile-ulimit-above-64000.html

But we are not sure that this is the solution

```
su postgres
bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.2.13)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
postgres=# select pid as process_id,
postgres-#        usename as username,
postgres-#        datname as database_name,
postgres-#        client_addr as client_address,
postgres-#        application_name,
postgres-#        backend_start,
postgres-#        state,
postgres-#        state_change
postgres-# from pg_stat_activity;
 process_id | username | database_name | client_address | application_name |         backend_start         |        state        |         state_change
------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------
      24182 | ambari   | ambari        | 127.0.0.1      |                  | 2019-05-29 08:20:12.136194+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 13:36:53.660075+00
      24184 | ambari   | ambari        | 127.0.0.1      |                  | 2019-05-29 08:20:12.330268+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:24.794683+00
      24185 | ambari   | ambari        | 127.0.0.1      |                  | 2019-05-29 08:20:12.346594+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:57.014266+00
      24186 | ambari   | ambari        | 127.0.0.1      |                  | 2019-05-29 08:20:12.352127+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:07:01.373678+00
      24192 | ambari   | ambari        | 127.0.0.1      |                  | 2019-05-29 08:20:14.736059+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:37.701989+00
      24499 | ambari   | ambari        | 127.0.0.1      |                  | 2019-05-29 08:20:47.801281+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:37.701784+00
      24500 | ambari   | ambari        | 127.0.0.1      |                  | 2019-05-29 08:20:47.801537+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:37.701784+00
      24501 | ambari   | ambari        | 127.0.0.1      |                  | 2019-05-29 08:20:47.801818+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:37.701956+00
      24502 | ambari   | ambari        | 127.0.0.1      |                  | 2019-05-29 08:20:47.934395+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:54.125167+00
      24628 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.91   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:12.959034+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:11.004364+00
      24620 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.91   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:10.674515+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:10.697886+00
      24621 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.91   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:10.866393+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:10.900711+00
      24624 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.91   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:12.11398+00  | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:05:46.928607+00
      24625 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.91   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:12.139117+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:14.719214+00
      24629 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.91   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:12.980466+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:11.005997+00
      24750 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.91   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:17.681669+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:14.713394+00
      24751 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.91   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:17.68909+00  | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:14.618542+00
      25223 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:27.016383+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:22.918908+00
      25293 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:27.394022+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:22.933555+00
      24818 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:23.344101+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 13:54:22.786162+00
      24819 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:23.364094+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 13:54:22.937269+00
      24820 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:23.377741+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 13:57:22.797683+00
      24821 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:23.389561+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 13:57:22.928034+00
      24822 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:23.397512+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:00:22.808355+00
      24823 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:23.411604+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:00:22.930902+00
      24824 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:23.420796+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:03:22.872217+00
      24825 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:23.42768+00  | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:03:23.033186+00
      25196 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:25.651445+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:22.79415+00
      24881 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:24.131849+00 | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:26.752754+00
      24884 | hive     | hive          | 34.22.1.93   |                  | 2019-05-29 08:21:24.16027+00  | idle                | 2019-05-29 14:06:26.754117+00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most all Hadoop services tend to have a lot of open files.  It's not uncommon for a production environment to have a 100K-200K open file descriptor limit.

The easiest solution is to raise the file descriptor limit.

Reference:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/how-can-i-increase-open-files-limit-for-all-processes

Comment: sorry , not understand the suggestion ?

Comment: do you suggest to update the  /etc/security/limits.conf  according to the link https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/48351/hiveserver2-hive-users-nofile-ulimit-above-64000.html  ?-  ( do you think is solve the issue about too many connection to postgres?

Comment: ok lets say I will do what was in the post , so do you think the hive connection will be much less ?

Comment: in our machine , the current configuration is * soft nofile 20000
* hard nofile 22000

Comment: I don't think 90 connections is unreasonable.  If you had several thousand, I'd be more concerned.  Also if you look at your connections, there are no idle connections several days old.  So the `hive.server2.idle.session.timeout` looks like it's working.

Comment: so do you recommended to add the follwing parameters to purge the connection - hive.server2.session.check.interval=6h
hive.server2.idle.operation.timeout=5d

hive.server2.idle.session.check.operation=true

hive.server2.idle.session.timeout=7d

Comment: this parameters are from the post - https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/202485/hiveserver2-configurations-deep-dive.html

Comment: I don't think you have to change anything other than raise your open file descriptor limit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194136/discussion-between-judy-and-tk421).

Comment: do you mean to increase the - fs.file-max = 500000 to higher value ? ( in /etc/sysctl.conf )

Comment: or to set higher value  for hive.conf as hive   - nofile 100000

Comment: You have to raise the system limit since changing the config without raising the system limit will generate exceptions.

Comment: so I need to raise both with the same value ?

Comment: if yes can you explain please how increasing both values affected on the hive connection to postgres?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear.  I don't think your 90 connections is a problem.  My recommendation is that most production clusters raise their open file descriptors limits to 100K-200K because most Hadoop/Hive components open a LOT of files.

Comment: I see other solution from other post about to increase postgres connection - what you think about - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778015/how-to-increase-the-max-connections-in-postgres  ???