# How to change Postgresql max_connections config via Kubernetes statefulset environment variable?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, digital-ocean

In Kubernetes, environment variables from a ConfigMap do not change the max_connections property in a PostgreSql pod. How do you change Postgres max_connections configuration via environment variables in Kubernetes ?

I've tried following parameters to configure Postgres.

The problem is, I can use DB, USER and PASSWORD parameters and values are set as expected. But i need to change max_connections configuration. I made related research, it looks like PGOPTIONS is the right choice to send configuration changes. Even i tried PGOPTIONS and other variations, there is no impact on max_connections value. I am connecting postgresql and i am executing SHOW MAX_CONNECTIONS query, it shows 100 even i specify 1000 in the environment configuration values.

I am using Kubernetes 1.14 in digitalocean.

#### ConfigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config-demo
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: demopostgresdb
  POSTGRES_USER: demopostgresadmin
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: demopostgrespwd
  PGOPTIONS: "-c max_connections=1000  -c shared_buffers=1024MB"
  POSTGRES_OPTIONS: "-c max_connections=1000  -c shared_buffers=1024MB"
  PG_OPTIONS: "-c max_connections=1000  -c shared_buffers=1024MB"
  MAX_CONNECTIONS: "1000"
```

#### Statefulset

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: pgdemo
spec:
  serviceName: "postgres"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:latest          

          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config-demo     
          env:         
            - name: PGOPTIONS
              value: "-c max_connections=1000  -c shared_buffers=1024MB"
            - name: "MAX_CONNECTIONS"
              value: "1000"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgredb
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgredb
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: postgres              
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: postgredb
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: do-block-storage
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 3Gi
```

I am expecting to get max_connections value as 1000.
But it looks like as default value like 100.

There is no error in any log.

Comment: Can you please share answer for it, if you are able to resolve it. Facing same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to extend the base image ( postgres:latest   ). overwrite the default configurations with custom changes and then launch postgres.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I dont understand why they share this information clearly; there is no permission to change connection limit via env options. Can you share an example about we can not change this information with env parameters in official documents ? I could not found.

Answer (score 9):

Postgresql docker image can only support several env parameters, `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`, `POSTGRES_USER` ,`POSTGRES_DB`, `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS`, `POSTGRES_INITDB_WALDIR`, `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD`, `PGDATA`.

If you want modify some database configuration parameters, you can use `args` in kubernetes.

**Deployment yaml file fraction**

```
  containers:
  - args:
    - -c
    - max_connections=1000
    - -c
    - shared_buffers=1024MB
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: postgres-config
    image: postgres
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: postgres
```

Answer (score 5):

When max_connections is specified by the environment variable of PGOPTIONS, the following error occurs. Therefore, it is correct to specify it in args instead of the environment variable of PGOPTIONS.

```
2020-05-27 06:51:55.327 UTC [62] FATAL:  parameter "max_connections" cannot be changed without restarting the server
psql: FATAL:  parameter "max_connections" cannot be changed without restarting the server
```

```
containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:latest
          args: ["-c", "max_connections=500"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres docker image does not allow to set `max_connections` property via environment variable. You have to use `postgresql.conf` file to set such configurations.

Create a ConfigMap using custom `postgresql.conf` file. Then mount the ConfigMap in `/etc/postgresql/` directory.

You will find a sample `postgresql.conf` file [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/misc/postgresql.conf.sample).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer; but mounting configmap as configuration gives read only file error; fyi.

Comment: For readonly error, first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584211/1290868, then try not to put conf file in the data mount and then "args" solution here works...