# Is it possible to kill previous replicaset without waiting for new replicaset to be rolled out?

Tags: kubernetes

## Context

Say we have `d.yaml` in which a deployment, whose strategy is `RollingUpdate`, is defined.

We first create a deployment:

```sh
kubectl apply -f d.yaml
```

After some time, we modify `d.yaml` and re-apply it to update the deployment.

```sh
vi d.yaml
kubectl apply -f d.yaml
```

This starts rolling out a new replicaset `R_new`.

Normally, the old (previous) replicaset `R_old` is *killed* only after `R_new` has successfully been rolled out.

## Question (tl;dr)

Is it possible to kill `R_old` without waiting for rolling out `R_new` to complete?

By "kill", I mean completely stopping a replicaset; it should never restart. (So `kubectl delete replicaset` didn't help.)

## Question (long)

In my specific situation, my containers connect to an external database. This single database is also connected from many containers managed by other teams.

If [the maximum number of connections allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778015/how-to-increase-the-max-connections-in-postgres) is already reached, new containers associated with `R_new` fail to start (i.e. `CrashLoopBackOff`).

If I could forcefully kill `R_old`, the number of connections would be lowered by `N` where `N` is the number of replicas, and thus `R_new`'s containers would successfully start.

**FAQ:**

Q. Why not temporarily stop using `RollingUpdate` strategy?

A. Actually I have no permission to edit `d.yaml`. It is edited by CI/CD.

Q. Why not just make the maximum number of connections larger?

A. I have no permission for the database either...

Comment: how about 1)scale down deployment to 0 2)make changes 3)  scaling up deployment ?

Comment: @confusedgenius By "scale", do you mean using `kubectl scale`? Or first deleting the deployment, modifying it and re-creating it?

Comment: i meant using ```kubectl scale`` command.

Comment: @confusedgenius It worked like a charm. I tried this order: (1) make changes (2) scale down (3) scale up, as it is more practical for me. Could you post it as an answer to let me accept it?

Comment: Thanks for confirming :) . Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Is it possible to kill R_old without waiting for rolling out R_new to complete?By "kill", I mean completely stopping a replicaset; it should never restart. (So kubectl delete replicaset didn't help.)

1. Make Changes to deployment
2. Scale down deployment to `replicas=0` so that it is as good as stopping the old replicaset
3. scale up deployment to desired number of `replicas`, new `replicasets` will be created with new configuration changes in deployment.

*steps number 1 & 2 can be interchanged based on the requirement*

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can delete the old replicaset by running `kubectl delete replicaset R_old` and this would terminate the old pod. I just verified it in my cluster (kubernetes version 1.21.8).

However, terminating a pod doesn't necessarily mean it is been killed immediately.
The actual termination of the pod depends on whether or not a [preStop lifecycle hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks) is defined, and on the value of terminationGracePeriodSeconds (see description by typing `kubectl explain pod.spec.terminationGracePeriodSeconds`).

By default, the kubelet deletes the pod only after all of the processes in its containers are stopped, or the grace period has been over.

Comment: In my case, `kubectl delete replicaset` didn't help. It actually once deleted the specified replicaset, but it was automatically recreated and started right after the deletion. (This is because a replicaset is manually killed but the deployment which manages the replicaset is alive, maybe?)

Comment: UPDATE: When I try your solution with a minimal setup, it worked as you say. So, the reason why it didn't help in my specific case is maybe because of another configuration which I failed to refer to in the OP... I'll try to find it.