# o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : FATAL: query_wait_timeout

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am using SpringBoot application with PostgreSQL as database, I am doing Load Testing from Jmeter, Database is hosted in azure, when I try to hit 150 Rest request to Single API or endpoint parallelly/concurrently, I am getting below error but with 100 request it works successfully.

**ERROR**:

```
2022-12-21 17:29:43.000  WARN 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-60] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08P01
2022-12-21 17:29:43.000 ERROR 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-60] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : FATAL: query_wait_timeout
2022-12-21 17:29:43.000  WARN 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-60] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
2022-12-21 17:29:43.001 ERROR 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-60] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
2022-12-21 17:29:43.090  WARN 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-61] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08P01
2022-12-21 17:29:43.090 ERROR 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-61] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : FATAL: query_wait_timeout
```

I want to improve the performance of the application in short solve the above error when we auto-scale our application with two instances, 150 request are passed but when we run with a single instance, it gives the above error, I want to understand

1. whether it is a memory issue or a db issue?
2. How to resolve it ?`

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html):

> **query_wait_timeout**
>
> Maximum time queries are allowed to spend waiting for execution. If the query is not assigned to a server during that time, the client is disconnected. 0 disables. If this is disabled, clients will be queued indefinitely. [seconds]
>
> This setting is used to prevent unresponsive servers from grabbing up connections. It also helps when the server is down or rejects connections for any reason.
>
> Default: 120

Most probably all the connections in the PostgreSQL connection pool are busy and your application fails to obtain one within the bounds of pre-defined timeout of 2 minutes.

The options are in:

1. [Increase connection pool size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778015/how-to-increase-the-max-connections-in-postgres)
2. Increase the aforementioned timeout
3. Check Postgresql [slow queries logs](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/3-ways-to-detect-slow-queries-in-postgresql/) and [execution plans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan) for these queries
4. Test the database in isolation using [JDBC Request sampler](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter)
5. Use a profiler tool like [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) to see whether the long processing is somewhere in your application source code.