# Postgresql database randomly crashes

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-1.7

I really have no idea what the problem is.

The logs read

> FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already

Over and over again. At first I thought that sometimes the connections lingered or were not closed properly so I tested that by connecting to the database and checking how many opened connections there were at any given time, and the answer has always been 1.

I tried to connect to the website that's using the DB and I managed to glimpse at 2 or 3 opened connections that were promptly closed when the page was done loading.

My remaining guess is that sometimes there are spikes in concurrent connections to the website and that causes the database to stop accepting new connections and somehow doesn't allow the current connections to be dropped.

I DID NOT WRITE ANY CODE THAT CONNECTS TO THE DATABASE, I'm using a pretty vanilla Django (1.7) backend that handles all of the connections.

I couldn't find anything while searching google, has anyone experienced any problems?

EDIT:

[Database configuration is here(PasteBin)](http://pastebin.com/nqWDtA3Y)

Essential part:

```
port = 26445                # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 500           # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directory = '/home/clearintent/webapps/norr2_db/run'        # (change requires restart)

shared_buffers = 32MB           # min 128kB
                    # (change requires restart)
log_destination = 'stderr'      # Valid values are combinations of
logging_collector = on          # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
log_directory = 'pg_log'        # directory where log files are written,
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'  # log file name pattern,
log_truncate_on_rotation = on       # If on, an existing log file with the
log_rotation_age = 1d           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
log_rotation_size = 0           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
lc_messages = 'C'           # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'C'           # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'C'            # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'C'               # locale for time formatting
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

Comment: That is not a crash, FYI.

Comment: Please include database configuration, maybe the problem is there.

Comment: @CraigRinger I think it is, I cannot even kill the process, I need to "kill -9" it

Comment: Check out `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` for clues.

Comment: It only shows my current connection, or the website 2 or 3 connections if it's currently visited. I should probably set up a cron job to output that table into a file every minute or so so I know what's going on before the crash but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: Maybe the following two problems are somewhat related and would help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2758432/3628578 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14191857/3628578. You could also check how many idle connections are there in the background.

Comment: Have you checked your django and web server configuration?  As explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/) it will maintain a connection per thread used to process a request.  I could believe a heavy spike would start a lot of threads and so max out your connections.  This would be even worse if you are using persistent connections.

Comment: Is your Django app running in a cluster? Is it possible that that any deadlock is being created, which keeps the connections open for ever?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like something is bashing your PostgreSQL but that error alone does not crash the DB.
It simply means the latest connection attempt exceeded the amount of allowed parallel connections to the DB and it was rejected.

But, if you want to dump the amount of connections every minute, you can use this script

```
#!/bin/bash

function spew_connections() {
# Run psql on local if trust or auth is set.
# Change dbadmin and dbname accordingly.
/usr/bin/psql -d dbname -U dbadmin -w -t -c "SELECT localtimestamp(2), count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity;"
}

echo -n `spew_connections` >> /tmp/connections
echo >> /tmp/connections
```

And then, to execute it using crontab every minute

```
crontab -e
*/1 * * * * /path/to/executable/script
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and come back with results after another crash.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install tools like [pgBouncer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) between Your app and database.

PgBouncer is a lightweight connection pooler for PostgreSQL.

Most important points:

```
[databases]
pgbase = host=localhost dbname=bazdb

[pgbouncer]
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432

pool_mode = transaction
```

And in client connect to `pgbase` on localhost:6432

Comment: Wouldn't this increase the number of connections I need?

Comment: No. pgBoucer manage connections to DB. I had the same problem on my system. pgBoucer resolved this problem definitly. When I catch my admin, then I paste this pgBoucer config.

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't close connections automatically.

Add

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'autocommit': True,
}
```

to Your database configuration.

Comment: Django [**does** close connections automatically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#conn-max-age). Auto-commit is [turned on by default since Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#autocommit-mode)

Comment: Yeah I would have been pretty shocked. I'm using Django 1.7. And also I would have seen the opened lingering connections after my tests.

Comment: @Steven Yes, You have right. I did not notice information about Django version.