# MySql connection managment with web app

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, amazon-web-services

I have a number of servlets (Spring MVC, Rest et...) which all need a database connection

I have a MYSQL database and I use mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar to make the connection

The servlets get hit a few hundred times a hour each and I want to improve performance

So how can the current design be improved? (current system is each request into the platform is handled by a servlet which creates a DB connection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> current system is each request into the platform is handled by a servlet which creates a DB connection

Use [connection pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/connection-pooling/info)

**Also See**

- [connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0)

Comment: Connection pooling is definately something you should look into.

Comment: will look into the pool built into tomcat