# Fast and reliable alternatives to bonecp connection pool

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, bonecp

I was using *BoneCP* for my *Java* projects. But, unfortunately, I discovered that this pool is unable to recover after the database failure. I am not the only one with such problem (just look at the official forums if you want). 
As I (and many others) never got answer on bonecp forums, it seems that this project is no longer supported and my issue is unlikely to be fixed.

So, I am looking for an alternative actively developed and supported connection pooling library which is able to handle database outages correctly and recover as soon as database is available again.

Comment: There are in fact no actively support CP libraries imo. Devs seemed to get bored of writing them and supporting them. See below for the most popular CP libraries used nonetheless

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other major contenders are

- [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) - also more or less abandoned, but very capable
- [Proxool](http://proxool.sourceforge.net/) - also abandoned
- [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp) - abandoned for a long time, restarted.
- [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) - new CP that even the BoneCP author [concedes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662916/311525) is [faster](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/)
- [Vibur](http://www.vibur.org/) - modern pool, with metrics and slow query logging
- [Tomcat JDBC Pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) - included with tomcat, but can be used standalone

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The fact that they are all abandoned is a bit strange to me, though. Every heavy-loaded java appliction that works with database needs connection pooling, right?

Comment: Sure, but apparently it's boring and unloved work. BoneCP looked very promising a couple of years ago, but followed the same trend - 2-4 years of intensive work and then boom.

Comment: BoneCP development is still on, the last snapshot version came out in Jan. 2013

Comment: Also DBCP, C3PO, have all their performance problems (leaks, dead locks, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

You might want to look at https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP. The speed claims are staggering, but it's new and YMMV.

Comment: springboot 2 prefers Hikari over TomcatJDBC which means that Hikari so these days it is the 'defacto standard' for java microservices in the large organisations that use springboot.

Answer (score 5):

Try jdbc-pool http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html bundled with Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another connection pool to try, which is fully concurrent and which can handle database outages correctly: http://www.vibur.org/

Comment: I have used in production with great success.  Really fast and reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Just would like to point out that BoneCP development has restarted.

Comment: is it still on? How does it compare now to other solutions available today ?

Comment: No, it hasn't, unfortunately.