# Why is DBCP still used instead of other Connection Pools?

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, database-connection, connection-pooling

After reading this article - "[Connection pooling options with JDBC: DBCP vs C3P0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0)"; About how Apache DBCP is out of date, not production graded and not supported by hibernate, I'm confused why people are still using it instead other connection pools like C3P0?

For example:
In this tutorial created May 2012 - [Spring Hibernate Integration Tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html)

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"> ... </bean>
```

Comment: Because not everything that people write in stack overflow is gold.

Comment: I prefer rathen Tomcat JDBC Pool. It is superior to Commons DBCP.

Answer (score 0):

The article you linked to says:

> UPDATE: It turns out that after many years of sitting on a shelf, the Apache
>   Commons folk have taken DBCP out of dormancy and it is now, once
>   again, an actively developed project. Thus my original post may be out
>   of date.

So, maybe the issues in the article have been met by others, or maybe they've been fixed now. Make up your own opinion.

Comment: Yes good pick up. 
Looking at http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/ the last updated date is 25 November 2010  on Version: 1.4.1-SNAPSHOT which is 1.5 years ago..

And in this article http://wiki.apache.org/commons/DBCP/Hibernate published on Jan 2011 it mentions limited support for DBCP on Hibernate 2.