# Overhead on using DB connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have a bunch of java programs that are run every few minutes. These programs are started by a script every few minutes and terminates in less than a minute. Most of them are single threaded and to access MySQL DB I use:

```
DriverManager.getConnection()
```

They just need to connect once, and execute a query.
Now I'm adding a new program to this group which is multi threaded and all the threads need to access DB concurrently. I'm thinking of using a DB connection pool (c3p0) for this.

My question is, as all these programs share a common DAO for accessing DB, is there an overhead of using a DB connection pool for the single threaded programs even though they just need one connection?
I'm planning to set initialPool size to 1, min pool size to 1 and max pool size to 10.

Answer (score 2):

The main goal of connection pools is to have some ready-to-use connections, rather then open and close each time you want to get a connection. This approach saves quite enough time in terms if DB is used quite often.

[Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) is single-threaded, but anyway it significantly increases performance, if your application uses DB connection very often.

c3p0 is a good choice, but for choosing proper connection pool please check this discussion: [Connection pooling options with JDBC: DBCP vs C3P0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0)

Comment: My question is if there is any performance issue on using a DB Connection Pool with just one connection vs just obtaining a connection using DriverManager.getConnection()

Comment: There shouldn't be any performance issues at least just because you won't close `Connection` at all. Since you are planning to set `maxPoolSize` to 10, then in this case ConnectionPool is a best choice as there won't be any locks. The only thing to consider is that ConnectionPool needs external libraries, meanwhile `DriverManager.getConnection()` needs only JDK.