# What is the best way to take database connection for pollling programs in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I am creating a polling program in java using TimerTask for to send email and other notifications automatically. Now this program every second check the database for any new data available.

Now i am creating connection like below

Connector class its holds database details and return a connection.

```
public class Connector implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ResourceBundle prop = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dbdetails");

    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        Connection con;
        Class.forName((String) prop.getString("DB_DRIVER"));
        con = DriverManager.getConnection((String) prop.getString("DB_URL"),
                (String) prop.getString("DB_USER"),
                (String) prop.getString("DB_PASS"));
        return con;

    }

}
```

My polling class

```
public class EmailPoller extends TimerTask {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EmailPoller.class);
    private Connector connector = new Connector();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null, ps1 = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = connector.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select to_addr,subject,content,id from email_notification where status='A'");
            ps1 = con
                    .prepareStatement("update email_notification set status='I' where id=?");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Boolean b = Mailer.sendMail(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2),
                        rs.getString(3));

                if (b) {
                    ps1.setInt(1, rs.getInt(4));
                    ps1.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.info("Email Poller Error : " + ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (ps1 != null) {
                    ps1.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.info("Email Poller Error : " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after send a email i am updating a flag. Mailer is sending mail perfectly.

Whether this is a correct approach to check the database for data or any other best way is there to connect to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to poll the database at a particular time period, 
- you should never create a connection every time you seek for something in the database. Create a connection once and `reuse` it, or let `DataSource` handle everything. You just request DataSource a connection and it gives you a connection.

You could slightly modify your `Connector` class as below to allow DataSource Implementations to handle connection pooling.

The below example uses the `MySql Implementation of the DataSource interface`. You could however change the implementations depending on what database you work on, by simply adding the corresponding jar to your classpath.

```
    class Connector implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static ResourceBundle prop = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dbdetails");
    private static MysqlDataSource dataSource = null;

    // Dont allow any instance of this class
    private Connector(){
    }

    private static void initDataSource()
    {
        try 
        {
            dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
            dataSource.setURL(prop.getString("DB_URL"));
            dataSource.setUser(prop.getString("DB_USER"));
            dataSource.setPassword(prop.getString("DB_PASS"));
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // handle the Exception according to your application demand
        }
    } 
    /*
     * Return a connection from the datasource pool 
     */
    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
       if(dataSource == null)
       {
           initDataSource();
       }
       return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

}
```

Although the above becomes more efficient, it is more suitable for `web applications` where a large number of requests need to be handled and connections to be pooled. Since your program is a `standalone code`, you could `ignore` connection pooling and simply go ahead just ensuring that your application has only one connection at any time. You could modify the Connector class as below:

```
class Connector implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static ResourceBundle prop = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dbdetails");;
private static Connection con = null;

// Dont allow any instance to be created for this class
private Connector(){
}

private static void initConnection() throws  Exception
{
    Class.forName((String) prop.getString("DB_DRIVER"));
    con = DriverManager.getConnection((String) prop.getString("DB_URL"),
            (String) prop.getString("DB_USER"),
            (String) prop.getString("DB_PASS"));
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    if(con == null)
    {
        initConnection();
    }
    return con;
}
```

}

get the connection as: `Connector.getConnection()`, following a `singleton` pattern.

Comment: thanks BarScream.i am using mysql as my database. for mysql do i need to typecast the datasource as mysqldatasource. can u provide the imports

Comment: You need to use the class - MysqlDataSource. See my updated answer. Download and add mysql-connector-java-2.0.14.jar to your classpath.

Comment: no mine is jsf based web application. so according to your idea can i follow the first answer.

Comment: @Ramakrishna, have updated to singleton in the web based approach too, take a look.

Comment: @BatScream 2.0.14? That is really a very old version.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, not familiar with mysql, you should use the latest version of the implementation jar.

Comment: @Ramakrishna, Please ensure you add the latest version of the implementation jar, as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe yours is the most efficient way of getting connections. Read about Connection pools and from your timer task, acquire a connection from the pool which would be more efficient and makes your job a lot easier in terms of managing the connections.

For starters you can check : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520585/2231632)